# JavaScript: My logic traversing multi-dimensional arrays

Tags: javascript, array

Consider the following:

Let's say below is the multi-dimensional, and you are given the starting point of `[2, 2]`.

```
const WORLD = [
        ['P', 'P', 'P', 'C', 'P'],
        ['P', 'M', 'P', 'C', 'P'],
        ['P', 'M', 'P', 'C', 'P'], <---- That would result the "P" at the 2nd index
        ['P', 'M', 'P', 'P', 'P'],
        ['P', 'M', 'P', 'P', 'P']
      ];
```

Each of those values represent a terrain type described separately:

```
const TERRAIN_TYPES = {
  'P': {
    obstacle: false,
    description: 'plains'
  },
  'M': {
    obstacle: true,
    description: 'mountains'
  },
  'C': {
    obstacle: true,
    description: 'crevasse'
  }
};
```

My question is this... At first blush when I see a multi dimensional array, I imagine some kind of dynamic algorithm one should be using to traverse through it. But the fact a starting point, and a legend regarding the terrain types is given is the following implementation brute force?

I have a function excerpt from a class which accepts some commands. Also I included the commands and directions this function can use:

```
const DIRECTIONS = ['N', 'S', 'E', 'W'];
const COMMANDS = ['L', 'R', 'F', 'B'];

 executeCommads(commands) {
    const LEFTCOMMAND = COMMANDS[0];
    const RIGHTCOMMAND = COMMANDS[1];
    const FORWARDCOMMAND = COMMANDS[2];
    const BACKWARDCOMMAND = COMMANDS[COMMANDS.length - 1]

    const loc = this.location
    const moveForward = this.location[1] - 1;
    const moveBackWard = this.location[1] + 1;
    const positionPossible = !this.positionPossible(WORLD[loc[0]][loc[1]])


    for (var i = 0; i < commands.length; i++) {

      if (commands[i] === LEFTCOMMAND) {
        this.direction = 'W'
      }

      if (commands[i] === RIGHTCOMMAND) {
        this.direction = 'E'
      }


      if (commands[i] === FORWARDCOMMAND) {
        if (positionPossible) {
          this.location[1] = moveForward
          break
        }
      }
      if (commands[i] === BACKWARDCOMMAND) {
        if (positionPossible) {
          this.location[1] = moveBackWard
          break
        }
      }
    }
    return {
      status: STATUS_CODES[0],
      loc: this.location,
      dir: this.direction
    }
  }
```

The part in question is this:

```
    const moveForward = this.location[1] - 1;
    const moveBackWard = this.location[1] + 1;
    const positionPossible = !this.positionPossible(WORLD[loc[0]][loc[1]])
```

I would *think* that makes a lot of sense, that function:

```
  positionPossible(value) {
    return TERRAIN_TYPES[value].obstacle
  }
```

checks the `WORLD[2][1]` if that position/terrain is a plain type, and then executes the COMMAND value passed i.e. `F` from the possible `['L', 'R', 'F', 'B']`

For 'F' it will be `const moveForward = this.location[1] - 1;`

Thus resulting in:

```
const WORLD = [
        ['P', 'P', 'P', 'C', 'P'],
        ['P', 'M', 'P', 'C', 'P'], <---- That would result the "P" at the 2nd index
        ['P', 'M', 'P', 'C', 'P'], 
        ['P', 'M', 'P', 'P', 'P'],
        ['P', 'M', 'P', 'P', 'P']
      ];
```

Hopefully that all makes sense, just wondering if that is kosher?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you clarify what your specific question is? If you have already-working code and want feedback on code style etc, then the [codereview.se] site might be more helpful. (However, I'm fairly sure that your code is not yet working as you intend because you're not actually using the direction.)

Comment: One strategy I can recommend for thinking through your problem clearly is “programming by wishful thinking”: So you want to `executeCommands()`. Imagine we already have `executeCommand()`, then you could implement `for (var c of commands) this.executeCommand(c)`. Next, implement the imagined function. For that, you might imagine `loc = positionAhead()` and `isObstacle(loc)` functions, and so on. But use them as functions, don't prematurely assign their results to variables that might be outdated when you access them later. For example, your `positionPossible` describes the *initial* position.